# multiple strokes gesture does not work to make a push - android

Tags: android, gesture, builder

I created a list of gestures with "gesture builder" and I am trying to make a gesture like a "i". If I make stick only works correctly but if I make stick and then I make the point, does not work. Does not even enter onGesturePerformed function. I am using other letters as "a", "e", "o", "u" (use a single gesture) and others such as "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" (I use more of one gesture). GestureOverlayView component added in the following parameters: "gesture stroke type = multiple" and "Fade offset = 2000". My impression is that it detects as if I did another event as "onTouch"...
I have seen that there is parameter: "enabled interception events". I've tried both, false and true and the problem continues.
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.